# How are likes recorded in firebase after a like button is pressed?

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have been working on getting likes recorded in firebase. ("the person who likes' UID" to go into "the person he liked's child reference").

I have connected the outlet, if pressed action, and have code to get it into firebase but somewhere I am producing nil for an optional.

```
    @IBAction func likePressed(_ sender: Any) {
    self.like.isEnabled = false
    let ref = Database.database().reference()
    let keyToPost = ref.child("likes").childByAutoId().key

    ref.child("people").child(self.postID).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with:  {(snapshot) in

        if let people = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject] {
            let updateLikes: [String: Any] = ["peopleWhoLike/\(keyToPost)" : Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid]
            ref.child("people").child(self.postID).updateChildValues(updateLikes, withCompletionBlock: { (error, rerr) in

                if error == nil {
                       ref.child("people").child(self.postID).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snap) in
                        if let properties = snap.value as?[String: AnyObject]{
                            if let likes = properties["peopleWhoLike"] as? [String : AnyObject] {
                                let count = likes.count
                                self.likeLabel.text = "\(count) Likes"

                            let update = ["likes" : count]
                                ref.child("people").child(self.postID).updateChildValues(update)


                            }

                        }
                    })
                }
            })

        }

    })

    ref.removeAllObservers()



}
```

////////////////inside homepage override func Table View:

```
 cell.postID = self.people[indexPath.row].postID
```

This is Json database structure:

```
"people" : {
"9RYUttVhCzXKs6H1XnZ63TZ8Dun2" : {
  "Coordinates" : {
    "latitude" : 15.78583,
    "longitude" : -4.406417
  },
  "Education" : "CS",
  "PhotoPosts" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/daylike-2f938.appspot.com/o/images%2FPhotoPosts?alt=media&token=ac9e574f-b55f-4bf0-b75b-79b877a86480",
  "caption" : 1563439869418,
  "users" : "nane19@aol.com"
},
"K1eqsVZfKGgIf0sS1UZcPNxY62x1" : {
```

At the end in the firebase database, under say user Ronald, the people who liked him will be listed(more accurately their uid). That will be under new child postID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found the error. The database didn't have a child postID, which should be the same as the uid. After adding that child at login, the error was fixed.